# sql query not inserting data in one specific coloumn

Tags: php, mysql

**Description :**

I was using localhost up till now and every thing was working fine . Couple of hours ago I put my website live and now weird things have started to happen.

I have a sql query as following :

```
if(mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO  `891368`.`posts` (
`posted_on_id`,
`poster_id`,
`post_type` ,
`post` ,
`likes` ,
`comments` ,
`post_date`
)
VALUES ('$posted_on_id', '$reg_no', 'text',  '$data',  '0',  '0','$datetime')"))
{
   // do other thing
}
```

this query works fine on local host but if I update status on my live version of the website every column of the table gets filed as it should but the column post remains empty ...

I have tried to change the name of the column (if I am stupid :/ ) but nothing changed .. I am not familiar with this odd behaviour ... why is doing that ??

Comment: What is in $data?   May contain some characters that cannot be stored to the database without escaping the data

Comment: $data has regular text data ... and I am using mysql_real_escape_string() before inserting the data ... I have started using mysqli_* functions just now ... so should I do that with escape string function as well ??

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your PHP file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything,  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: i thought this, but i think the problem is somewhere else. seems nothing wrong with your query. if your data has a `'` character, then sql statement will have sytax error, so the row won't be inserted. you sad, it's inserted, just the post field is empty. It means for me, the `$data` is empty. What version of php do you use?

Comment: can you echo your querry plz?

Comment: $data is not empty see , after data gets inserted in the if condition same variable gets echo on the page and it shows the data fine ... its just data doesnt get inserted in the post coloumn ... size of the post column is 250 varchar ... is that ok ??

Comment: You may have to escape all you variables. try mysql_escape_string($posted_on_id) mysql_escape_string($reg_no)  mysql_escape_string($data) and see if that helps. If not, can you please show me you show create table for the production table and for the non-production table? also can you please echo 1 row of the variables that is not being inserted correctly?

Comment: Make sure your column types are correct and that the length number is large enough to accomodate the data being inserted.

Comment: Put your query into a variable, and dump it, and please show us.

Comment: I noticed in some of your other questions where you are using `mysql_*` functions. If your DB connection is `mysql_` based, then it won't work with what you posted. Those two MySQL APIs do not mix together.

Comment: @Fred-ii- :  "its just data doesnt get inserted in the post coloumn" he sad. So the error will be somewhere else, since, the record is inserted.

Comment: @Sparky You gave a clue sure it was something wrong with the filtration of the data I was using strip_slashes and real_escape_string and al those functions I have replaced them all with htmlspecialchars() and every thing is back to normal ... thanks guys ... I really appreciate it .. :)